# IF Statement in Case select vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Select Case choice

      Case "data1"
        If A = "aaa" Or A = "bbb" Or A = "cccc" Then

        .ComboBox8 = .ComboBox6
        .TextBox15 = .TextBox2
        .ComboBox9 = .ComboBox7
        .TextBox18 = .TextBox14
        .TextBox16 = .TextBox10
        .ComboBox16 = .ComboBox15
        .ComboBox25 = .ComboBox22
        .Repaint
        Else
        MsgBox "please check data. data is not aaa, bbb or ccc." & vbLf & _
        "Data Transfer Cancelled"
        
        End If
      Case "data2"
        If B = "aaa" Or B = "bbb" Or B = "ccc" Then
        .ComboBox13 = .ComboBox10
        .TextBox20 = .TextBox7
        .ComboBox14 = .ComboBox11
        .TextBox22 = .TextBox19
        .TextBox21 = .TextBox11
        .ComboBox12 = .ComboBox5
        .ComboBox24 = .ComboBox23
        .Repaint
        Else
        MsgBox "please check data. data is not aaa, bbb or ccc." & vbLf & _
        "Data Transfer Cancelled"
        End If
    End Select
```

I have 2 different buttons to trigger that codes. when clicking button data1, data in A need to be  aaa, bbb, or ccc. if it is then data moving, if not then I need get the warning msgbox and data cannot be moved.
same for button data2.
although, for that code when I click data1 or data2 getting msgbox error which is in my code independently from A or B data.

A and B are combobox statements. for example below code is working inside the same code.

```
  If IsEmpty(A) Then
    MsgBox "Please FILL A Data!", vbOKOnly, "Missing Data"
    UserForm5.MultiPage1.Value = 2
    UserForm5.ComboBox6.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
  End If
```

also below code is working if I do not use if statement.

```
    Select Case choice

      Case "data1"
        .ComboBox8 = .ComboBox6
        .TextBox15 = .TextBox2
        .ComboBox9 = .ComboBox7
        .TextBox18 = .TextBox14
        .TextBox16 = .TextBox10
        .ComboBox16 = .ComboBox15
        .ComboBox25 = .ComboBox22
        .Repaint

      Case "data2"
        .ComboBox13 = .ComboBox10
        .TextBox20 = .TextBox7
        .ComboBox14 = .ComboBox11
        .TextBox22 = .TextBox19
        .TextBox21 = .TextBox11
        .ComboBox12 = .ComboBox5
        .ComboBox24 = .ComboBox23
        .Repaint

    End Select
```

**Last Edit below code is also working**

```
          If B = "aaa" Or PsType = "ccc" Or PsType = "ddd" Or PsType = "eee" Or PsType = "bbb" Then
      If C = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please FILL C!", vbOKOnly, "Missing Data"
        UserForm5.MultiPage1.Value = 5
        UserForm5.TextBox7.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
      End If
```

Comment: Seems like the problem is that A and B don't match your defined values, so what are the values of A and B?

Comment: @TimWilliams B is defined as .ComboBox10.List = Array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg", "hhh")   .ComboBox10 = B and same for combobox6 which is defined for A.

Comment: `ComboBox10 = B` or do you mean that `B = ComboBox10`?

Comment: Seems like there's a bunch of code not shown which could likely account for the problem you're having, but unless we can see the whole thing it's unlikely we can help out much.  Does "getting msgbox error" mean you only ever see the "please check data" messagebox ?

Comment: @Toddleson it is combobox10 = B

Comment: Then you have not assigned any value to `B`. For a value to be assigned into `B`, you need to write `B = ComboBox10`

Comment: @TimWilliams unfortunately there are tones of codes working together one of them trigger the other one. this is an userform usage codes and all related with the other one.  that is why I could not share the entire code and also excel has lots of confidential names etc for the company. that is why I can only share the part of the code which is not working properly. Only the part what I do not understand all worked codes that I mentioned is working and that one is not.

Comment: @Toddleson sorry about that did not seen B = .ComboBox10.List(.ComboBox10.ListIndex)

Comment: @Toddleson after your suggestion about assignment. I have replaced the code as  if .combobox6 = "aaa" ...... and now it is working. I do not understand normally there lots of  codes working with same logic. anyway. thanks for your guidance.